How I can install Python3 on Pepper robot?
I would like to install Python 3 on the Pepper robot.
I have a Pepper robot with NAOqi 2.5.10.7 and Python 2.7.6
I would like to install Python 3 because it is needed for Pepper chat (https://github.com/ilabsweden/pepperchat).
How I can install Python 3 on the robot?
